# Where is the default connection timeout setting for my Power BI application and can I change it?

Tags: teradata, powerbi

Our Power BI data refreshes frequently fails with the error:

> ADO .NET Data Provider For Teradata timeout

Both Teradata and Power BI gateway are on-premise.

Someone mentioned that by default the connection timeout for Teradata is 30 sec.

My question is where can I see that setting, and can I change it for my Power BI application in the gateway server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with powerbi, but just for clarification, are you connecting through "Other>>ODBC" or through "Database>>Teradata" type connection? (I'm guessing "Database" since it's .net).

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting up your connection to Teradata there is an "Advanced Options" you can click on. "Command Timeout in Minutes" is one of the options available:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I will give it a try and let you know.